# Need To Resize Images Exactly Without Losing Image Details

Tags: functions, images

I am working on a Wordpress site that heavily uses image uploading and whatnot, I have defined the image sizes in my functions.php and I have hard crop mode turned on which ensures that my images are always cropped to the exact size that I want.

The problem with hard cropping is that peoples faces in images and other artefacts are cropped out and the images look ridiculous. Is there a way to have soft cropping mode turned on and have images always be an exact size?

I find that when I use soft cropping mode, images vary in height and width. So an image I want to be 110x110 in soft crop mode can vary and sometimes be 110x96 or whatever and because that makes the layout look crappy and some photos look landscape, what is the best way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the source image, aspect ratio is not magic, it must be maintained in order to lessen the proportional distortion.

You best option is to upload images that will maintain the same aspect ratio.

You can tweak your CSS to get a more consistent image size but be aware that doing so will create distortion the further it moves away from the proper aspect ratio.

Comment: Wow, forgot to choose an answer on this, my bad. Your answer was the most sensible and I have since worked out a compromise of giving people a crop tool to crop the images to exact proportions.